# Relação entre duas tabelas

Tags: java, mysql

olá, gostaria de saber como devo fazer para criar um relacionamento entre duas tabelas, Time e Partida, sendo que na partida eu devo colocar as colunas: time1, placar1, time2, placar2, e uma data.
Mas a minha dúvida é se eu preciso informar os campos dos times nessa tabela ou se isso vai ocorrer, na tabela de relacionamento, ficando na tabela Jogos apenas as outras colunas sem os times.
[image: relação de duas tabelas]

Comment: Na tabela jogos, você não precisa do Time, você precisa do ID do time. A partir dessa concepção, crie um relacionamento inserindo o id dos times ao invés do nome.

Answer (score 2):

do jeito que está modelado, troca o:
 time1: VARCHAR(50)
da tbl_jogos por uma chave estrangeira do id_Times.

O mesmo para o:
 time2: VARCHAR(50)

assim, quando você criar uma partida na tabela jogos, você terá 2 ids de times na tabela tbl_jogos e poderá obter qualquer informação desses times por esse relacionamento.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

O ideal é que em cada jogo, fique armazenado os times que jogaram. Para melhorar ainda mais, no lugar do nome de cada Time  id respectivo. Assim cada linha adicionada à tabela formaria um jogo, deixando sua tabela de relacionamento (que, obviamente, não sei quais relacionamentos você pensar em fazer) para resolver outras questões relacionadas a cada jogo, como por exemplo:

Tabela de relacionamento "**campeonatosDoBrasil**" que guarda o id de cada campeonato existente no Brasil

(Id 1350 - Brasileirão, id 1360 - Copa Do Brasil)

e o id de cada jogo que foi jogado no mesmo:

(id 1450 - Jogo 1 (data1, id 1550 - Flamengo, placar1 - 2, id 1650 -  Vasco, placar2 - 2))
(id 1460 - Jogo 2 (data2, id 1570 - Palmeiras, placar1 - 1, id 1580 -  São Paulo, placar2 - 1)).

[image]

Primeira tabela - tabela de Jogos
Segunda tabela - tabela de Campeonatos

Espero que eu tenha conseguido ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

- Dica:

Creio que seria mais legal adicionar na segunda tabela **tbl_jogos** dois campos: **id_time1** e **id_tim2** como chaves estrangeiras, imagine que chega um ponto do seu projeto que você queira puxar informações de cada time do jogo, com o nome dá certo? Dá sim, mas vai que dependendo de quem for preencher, acaba tendo nomes iguais ou sla, com o id isso não ocorreria. Como o @Luis Felipe disse, assim você tem as informações de todos os 2 times a qualquer hora sem precisar de muito esforço, basta fazer um `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_jogos` AS jogo INNER JOIN `tbl_time` AS time ON jogo.id_time_1 = time.id_Times WHERE jogo.id_Jogos = 1
```

Nessa query você pega todas as informações do **Time 1** e do **jogo**, também poderia fazer do **Time 2** simultaneamente, sem precisar de várias querys ou coisa do tipo.

Para criar chaves estrangeiras é fácil:

```
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT `sua tabela` (id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, id_segunda_tabela int NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(`id_segunda_tabela`) REFERENCES `segunda_tabela`(`id_da_segunda_tabela`) ON DELETE CASCADE)`
```

Perceba o `ON DELETE CASCADE`, este serve para excluir também o registro filho caso o registro da tabela principal, no contexto `segunda_tabela`, for excluído